# Apache 2.4 PHP 7.0 and 7.2 on separated virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache

I have installed PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.2 on the Debian 9 (Google Cloud). As default is 7.0 and I'd like to keep it now.
For some virtual host, I'd like to use 7.2. I found a few options how to run it when one PHP version is as FPM package. I installed it as standard version PHP + apache module. As separated both versions work ok.

Interpreters are insalled standard as `/usr/bin/php7.0` and `/usr/bin/php7.2`

Thanks in advance for any hints.

BWT Before you click the arrow down for this post, please think a moment. The Internet is full answers but about FPM, I'd like to use without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to load two versions of `mod_php` at once.